# Knockout.js "select all" checkboxes

Tags: javascript, input, checkbox, knockout.js

I've just started playing around with Knockout.js, and it seems really cool. What I have is a grid. This grid has a column with a checkbox at the top to "select all" of the elements, as well as deselect. Standard grid behavior.

Here's my code so far:

**Javascript:**

```
// Define a "banner" class
function banner(inventory, name, artType, artSize) {
    return {
        isSelected : ko.observable(false),
        inventory : ko.observable(inventory),
        name : ko.observable(name),
        artType : ko.observable(artType),
        artSize : ko.observable(artSize)

    };
}

var viewModel = {
    banners : ko.observableArray([new banner("network", "Banner #1"), new banner("oo", "Banner #2")]),
    addBanner : function() {
        this.banners.push(new banner("network", "Banner"));
    },
    selectAll : function() {
        this.banners.isSelected(true)
    }       

};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

I'm binding the "selectAll" event to the checkbox like this:

```
<th><input data-bind="click: selectAll" type="checkbox" /></th>
```

And for each individual banner I have in my list, their checkbox looks like this:

```
<td><input data-bind="checked: isSelected" type="checkbox" /></td>
```

For some reason my selectAll function isn't working correctly. I'm fairly new to this OO javascript programming paradigm, so I may be doing something blatantly wrong here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

banners is an array in this case, so you would need to access each item in the array and update the individual isSelected properties.

Something like:

```
ko.utils.arrayForEach(this.banners(), function(banner) {
   banner.isSelected(true);
});
```

Comment: Great, that works. Thanks. However, the initial checkbox at the top of the grid does not get checked. Basically I want it so that if the checkbox at the top is checked, all of them are checked. If not, all of them are not checked.

Comment: Your function needs to return true for the default action to happen.  Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/qFbUT/

Comment: Also, a slightly nicer way to do this toggling here: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/eT7xV/.

Comment: Thanks! Probably should be a separate question, but is there an easy to way see the updating results of banners() as changes are made to the array? console.log doesn't seem to work.

Comment: You should be able to console.log(viewModel.banners());  Otherwise, many times I add a div add the bottom of my page that looks like:
<div data-bind="text: ko.toJSON(viewModel.banners)"></div>

Comment: Where can I find a list of the util functions like "arrayForEach" and "toJSON"?

Comment: Most are not currently documented, but I wrote a blog post about some of the most useful ones here: http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/04/utility-functions-in-knockoutjs.html.

Comment: A little late, but what if one of the options was already selected, and I wanted clicking the "select all" checkbox to clear all selections if any existed. It would only select all if none were selected. This is how Gmail works. I can't see a way to do this either using a click binding or a subscribe.

Answer (score 1):

There's a more functional response at the link below. It deselects the "select all" box when on of the other checkboxes are deselected:

[knockout check/uncheck all combo box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9081546/knockout-check-uncheck-all-combo-box)