# Knockout Select/Unselect all and get the selected row values

Tags: knockout.js

I am trying create a select/un-select all using knockout and get the values of the rows selected to save.

I was able get select all and un-select all to work but not sure how to get the data of the selected rows.

Also if select a row check box every rows check box gets selected or un-selected.  If I unselect a check box I want the select all checkbox to be unchecked.

I created a fiddle of what I have done so far http://jsfiddle.net/adriandcosta/ewprL5bd/4/

This is my code:

```
<div style="height:40px">Results</div>
<div id="results" style="display:none" data-bind="visible: showResults">
    <table width="100%" id="tblSearchResults" data-bind="visible: SearchResults().length>0">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th align="left">Name</th>
                <th>Gender</th>
                <th align="left">DOB</th>
                <th align="left">Join Date</th>
                <th style="width:26px">
                    <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: allSelected" />
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="EmpResults" data-bind="template: { name:'TmplSearchResults', foreach: SearchResults }"></tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

**The template**

```
<script type="text/html" id="TmplSearchResults">
    <tr style = "border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC;"> 
        <td valign = "middle" data-bind="text: name"> </td>
       <td valign="middle" align="center" data-bind="text: gender"></td > 
        <td valign = "middle"   data-bind = "text: dob" ></td> 
     <td valign="middle" data-bind="text: joindate"></td > 
        <td valign = "middle" > 
            <input type = "checkbox" data-bind = "checked:$parent.isSelected" > 
                </td> 
    </tr>
</script>
```

**View Model and Data**

```
var vmSearchResult;
var vmSearchResultsModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.showResults = ko.observable(false);
    self.SearchResults = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.isSelected = ko.observable(false); // check box
    self.allSelected = ko.observable(false); // all select checkbox

    self.allSelected.subscribe(function (newValue) {

        ko.utils.arrayForEach(vmSearchResult.SearchResults(), function (PartnerSearch) {
            vmSearchResult.isSelected(newValue);  //<== here I get the selected values need the whole row

        });
    });
}

    function ShowData() {
    vmSearchResult.SearchResults(fakeData);
        vmSearchResult.showResults(true);

    }

$(document).ready(function () {
    vmSearchResult = new vmSearchResultsModel();
    ko.applyBindings(vmSearchResult, document.getElementById("results"));
    ShowData();
});
//Fake data  
var fakeData = [{
    "name": "Adrian D'Costa",
        "dob": "25-10-1984",
        "gender": "M",
        "joindate": "30-12-2004"
}, {

    "name": "Janet D'Curz",
        "dob": "30-08-1992",
        "gender": "F",
        "joindate": "15-12-2005"
}];
```

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9081546/knockout-check-uncheck-all-combo-box) out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to use a [Writable computed observable](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computed-writable.html) for the allSelected property instead of a normal observable.

When writing to the computed observable you can manage the selected state of each row now.

Example:

```
self.allSelected = ko.computed({
    read: function () {
        var firstUnchecked = ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.searchResults(), function (item) {
            return item.isSelected() == false;
        });
        return firstUnchecked == null;
    },
    write: function (value) {
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.searchResults(), function (item) {
            item.isSelected(value);
        });
    }
}).extend({ rateLimit: 1 });
```

With this approach you'll no longer need to subscribe to changes for allSelected.

The [rateLimit](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/rateLimit-observable.html) extender will need to be used to avoid slow performance when the list of items grows to any significant size.  The rateLimit extender was added in KO 3.1 and your fiddle is referencing 2.3.  The fiddles I provided are using 3.2.

FYI, this approach assumes that you'll have an isSelected observable property on each row.  You didn't have this in your example.  In the attached fiddle you can see how I added that.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ewprL5bd/13/)

Performance fiddles:

- [1000 items with rateLimit](http://jsfiddle.net/ewprL5bd/10/)
- [1000 items without rateLimit](http://jsfiddle.net/ewprL5bd/11/)

Comment: Thanks.  Your fiddle works as I want.  Will try it in my application and let you know.  I am using 3.1 in my app.  The fiddle that I linked was an older one :)

Comment: I tried your fiddle but somehow it does not select all.  Also I am not sure what you mean that I did not have an observable for each row isSelected.  I was assuming if I declare it in the viewmodel it means the same.  I had this  self.isSelected = ko.observable(false); and for each row I had referred it with $parent.isSelected.  I assume you mean something else.

Comment: The computed shows undefined in the read - return item.isSelected() === false;  This line

Comment: The way you coded the isSelected caused there to be a single instance of the isSelected observable on the root vm.  The $parent.isSelected binding referenced this single instance for each row in the table which in return would cause every row to be checked/unchecked when you clicked a single row.